# How transform this json to an array like that?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, transform

I got a problem. I work with an mcq generator in python flask. My backend work, but i have problem with my font end (i never use javascript before).

My python generator give me a json like that :

```
["{\"isMulti\": false, \"question\": {\"en\": \"What is the maximum number of IP addresses that can be assigned to hosts on a local subnet that uses the 255.255.255.224 subnet mask?\"}, \"answers\": [{\"en\": \"30\"}, {\"en\": \"14\"}, {\"en\": \"16\"}, {\"en\": \"15\"}], \"other\": {}}", "{\"isMulti\": false, \"question\": {\"en\": \"Which of this is not a class of IP address?\"}, \"answers\": [{\"en\": \"Class D\"}, {\"en\": \"Class F\"}, {\"en\": \"Class C\"}, {\"en\": \"Class E\"}], \"other\": {}}"]
```

And i want an javascript array like that :

```
  const myQuestions = [
    {
      question: en : "What is the maximum number of IP addresses that can be assigned to hosts on a local subnet that uses the 255.255.255.224 subnet mask?",
      isMulti: "false",
      answers: {
        en: "30",
        en: "14",
        en: "16",
        en: "15",
      },
    },
    {
      question: "question2",
      isMulti: "true",
      answers: {
        en: "erer",
        en: "wqrwerq",
        en: "wrwrw"
      },
    }
]
```

I have absolutly no idea to do that, and i need to keep the "en" information.
"en" is a key for the traduction.
can be "fr", "it", etc

My frontend generator work with a n array like that :

```
 const test =  [ 
{
      question: "Where i live?",
      isMulti: "True",
      answers: {
        1: "Paris",
        2: "Madrid",
        3: "Bresil",
        4: "Russia",
        5: "Johanesbrug",
        6: "Bruxelles"
      },
    }
  ];
```

Comment: You can't have an object where multiple keys share the same name like this: `{en: "30", en: "14", en: "16"}` You _could_ have an array of objects like this though: `[{en: "30"}, {en: "14"}, {en: "16"}]`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rounin has pointed out, you can't do exactly what you want.  However JSON.parse() on the string for each element in the array comes close.  The map() function lets you call that on each array member:

```
const input = ["{\"isMulti\": false, \"question\": {\"en\": \"What is the maximum number of IP addresses that can be assigned to hosts on a local subnet that uses the 255.255.255.224 subnet mask?\"}, \"answers\": [{\"en\": \"30\"}, {\"en\": \"14\"}, {\"en\": \"16\"}, {\"en\": \"15\"}], \"other\": {}}", "{\"isMulti\": false, \"question\": {\"en\": \"Which of this is not a class of IP address?\"}, \"answers\": [{\"en\": \"Class D\"}, {\"en\": \"Class F\"}, {\"en\": \"Class C\"}, {\"en\": \"Class E\"}], \"other\": {}}"];
const result = input.map(x => JSON.parse(x));
```

Now result[0] is:

```
{
    "isMulti":false,
    "question":{"en":"What is the maximum number of IP addresses that can be assigned to hosts on a local subnet that uses the 255.255.255.224 subnet mask?"},
    "answers":[{"en":"30"},{"en":"14"},{"en":"16"},{"en":"15"}],"other":{}}
}
```

and result[1] is:

```
{
    "isMulti":false,
    "question":{"en":"Which of this is not a class of IP address?"},
    "answers":[{"en":"Class D"},{"en":"Class F"},{"en":"Class C"},{"en":"Class E"}],"other":{}
}
```

As you can see there are some objects there where you don't want them.  If that isn't good enough you can tweak the output by providing a reviver parameter to the JSON.parse.  This iterates over the results and can be used to look for key names and change the associated value.  [See the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).